# Tell a networked scanner to scan via command line?

Tags: command-line, scripts, scanner, epson

I have a network scanner. I would like to tell it to scan, and send my PC the document, and I would like to do this via the command line. what is the simplest option?
The scanner, is part of a printer scanner all-in-one, Epson WorkForce WF-3520.

Comment: What is your scanner, does it scan from GUI?

Comment: im looking for command line options, or C++ examples.  Im not interested in doing this via a gui.

Comment: I am asking this because it is unclear what is your scanner and is a driver installed.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was thinking there must be a std protocol or somethign

Comment: There is no standard protocol, that's the problem. But it is possible to do using CLI for many scanners. It is possible to do for your scanner. I am writing the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to install the driver.

Go to [Epson Drivers Site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule) and search for your scanner model.

If your system is 64-bit, you will need these packages:

- iscan_2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb
- iscan-data_1.36.0-1_all.deb
- iscan-network-nt_1.1.1-1_amd64.deb

After you install these drivers you will need to edit `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` file and add there a line

```
net <ip_address>
```

where `<ip_address>` is the IP of your scanner.

Then you will be able to scan using `scanimage` utility.

You can see how to use it by running

```
man scanimage
```

If you have only one scanner connected, the default command is

```
scanimage > output_file
```